# Prove that there is $i$ for which $i\in B$ and $i+1\in A$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $n \geq 3, \ A,B \subseteq \{2,...,n-1\}, \ A,B \neq \emptyset $ and $|A|+|B| \geq n$. Show that there is such $i$ that $i\in B $ and $i+1 \in A$.

My attempt:

Since $\ A,B \subseteq \{2,...,n-1\}$ and $|\{2,...,n-1\}| = n-2$ we have $|A \cup B| \leq n -2$ (because there is at most $n-2$ distinct elements).

Let $X=\{a-1: a\in A\}$. Then $X \subseteq \{1,...,n-2\}$. Of course, $|X|=|A|$. Since we added one new element which can be in $X \cup B$ (and from the fact that $B \subseteq \{2,...,n-1\}, \ X \subseteq \{1,...,n-2\}$), we have $|X \cup B| \leq n-1$ since in this sum of sets there can be at most $n-1$ distinct values.

Now
$$|X \cap B| = |X| + |B| - |X \cup B|$$
$$|X \cap B| = |A| + |B| - |X \cup B|$$
Since
$$ |X \cup B| \leq n -1$$
$$ -|X \cup B| \geq -n +1$$
$$ n-|X \cup B| \geq n-n +1$$
$$ n-|X \cup B| \geq 1$$

Because $|A| + |B| \geq n$ we can write

$$ |X \cap B| =|A| + |B|- |X \cup B|  \geq n-|X \cup B| \geq 1$$
So
$$ |X \cap B| \geq 1$$
So there is $i \in X \cap B$. Finally, $i\in X \implies i+1 \in A$.

Comment: "Also  because of $|A|+|B| \geq n$, $|A \cup B|=n-2$" This is wrong. Consider, for example $A=B$, both with $n/2$ elements. It might be easier to prove the statement via the contrapositive.

Comment: @AndreasLenz I tried to correct my proof, could you look at it?

Comment: Your title and question are not the same; I assume that the title is in error, but maybe you can edit to clarify?

Comment: @BrianTung, yes, thank you, my bad.

Comment: +1 To your question.  Nice re-write.  Your proof looks good.  If there is a flaw in your proof, I can't find it.

Comment: @user2661923 thank you for bearing with me and for the alternate proof :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dispute the statement that:

because $|A| + |B| \geq n,$
that you must then have that 
(in effect) $(A \cup B) = \{2,3,\cdots, (n-1)\}.$

That is, I see no reason that $A$ and $B$ can't have a sufficient number of *shared* elements, that then $|A| + |B| \geq n$ is satisfied, even though $(A \cup B)$ is not equal to $\{2,3,\cdots, (n-1)\}.$

---

My alternate proof is the following:

Assume that $|B| = r \implies r \in \{1,2,\cdots, (n-2)\}.$

Order the distinct elements in $B$ in ascending order, 
as $a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_r$
so that $a_1 < a_2 < \cdots < a_r.$

For $i \in \{1,2,\cdots, r\}$ 
let $b_i$ denote $(a_i + 1).$

Assume that the constraint that there exists an element $x$ such that $x \in B$ and $(x+1)\in A$ is violated.

**Edit**
Without loss of generality, $r > 1$, else the max value of $|A| + |B| = (n-2) + 1 < n$.

Then, none of $b_1, b_2, \cdots, b_{r-1}$ can be in $A$, and each of $b_1, b_2, \cdots, b_{r-1}$ must represent a distinct element in $\{2,3,\cdots, (n-1)\}.$

Therefore, the most elements that the set $A$ can have is 
$[(n-2) - (r-1)]$.

This implies that the largest value achievable by 
$|A| + |B|$
is $r + [(n-2) - (r-1)] = (n-1).$

Comment: Thanks for the answer and for pointing out my mistake. I tried to correct my proof, maybe now it is ok.

Comment: @Awerde No, the objection to your logic that Andreas Lenz and I each (independently) indicated still pertains.  That is, $A$ and $B$ could have enough **shared** elements so that $(A \cup B)$ is not equal to $\{2,3,\cdots, n-2\}$, despite $A$ and $B$ satisfying $|A| + |B| \geq n$.

Comment: @Awerde I don't see how the assertion can be proven without noticing that if $|B| = r$, then $(r-1)$ elements from $\{2,3,\cdots,(n-1)\}$ have been eliminated as possibly being in set $A$.  More informally, if you assume that $B$ starts out with the element $(n-1)$, then each additional element added to $B$ causes there to be an additional element that can not be in $A$.

Comment: The previous comment is based on the *contrapositive* approach which was also suggested by the comment of Andreas Lenz.  That is, assume that the constraint that there exists some special element $x$ in $B$ such that $(x+1)$ is in $A$ is **violated**.  Then, use this assumption to prove that $|A| + |B| \leq (n-1)$.

Comment: but now I'm not assuming that $|A \cup B| = n - 2$, I know that it is at most $|A \cup B| \leq n - 2$ which I think is ok, since we really cannot go beyond that with $n-2$ elements. Thanks again for your answer, I was suggested to use the equation $|X\cap B| = |X| + |B| - |X \cup B|$ and shifting the $A$ set, so I really wanted to give it a shot.

Comment: @Awerde First of all, now that you have edited your proof, I am unsure whether you may be able to transform it into a valid argument.  Initially, once I saw the mistake around incorrectly assuming that $|A \cup B| = (n-2)$, I stopped reading.  This means that I never focused on your attempt to involve $X \subseteq \{1,2,\cdots,n-2\}$ and your approach of trying to prove that $|X \cap B| \geq 1.$  I am unsure, but your approach may be viable.  I have a couple of concerns. ...see next comment

Comment: @Awerde [1] If I am not mistaken, you are assuming that $|X \cap B| = |A \cap B|.$  This is almost correct, but overlooks that $(n-1)$ could be in $A \cap B|$ but can not be in $|X \cap B|$. [2] Your proof is very difficult to follow, because of all of the leftover analysis from your first attempt.  I suggest that you write out your new proof, using your idea of the set $X \subseteq \{1,2,\cdots,n-2\}$ step by step on paper, and nail down your logic.  ...see next comment

Comment: @Awerde Then, I suggest that you completely edit your question, deleting everything currently there, and replacing it with your new proof.  Then, flag me when done.  This will make it easier for me to examine your new proof, **line by line**.

Comment: I rewrote the whole proof, hope it is more clear now. Thanks for answering ;)

Comment: @Awerde See the comment that I just left, following your question.